# Windows Python Selenium Webdriver can only run in headless Chrome and not in Chrome with UI

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome

I have issues running Selenium in the normal Chrome with UI but the code works with headless chrome. It works for people with Mac with the normal Chrome.
I get following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "privacy-api-backend/website-functions/acxiom.py", line 56, in <module>
    acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email)
  File "privacy-api-backend/website-functions/acxiom.py", line 20, in acxiom_DD_formfill
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in _init_
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in _init_
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

When I don't run the Chrome options which are commented out here:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import time
def acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email):
    # chrome_options = Options()
    # chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    # chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    # chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    # chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    # chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.set_window_size(1124, 850) # set browser size
    # link to data delete form
    print("opening data delete form")
    driver.get("https://isapps.acxiom.com/optout/optout.aspx#section8")
    #Select opt out segment: Following option values: "Mail", "Telemarketing", "Email"
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.ss-values"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ss-values"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ss-option' and contains(.,'Email')]"))).click()
    #ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='OptOutChoices2']/option[@value='Mail']") 
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",ele)
    print("dropdown selected")
    #Select identity: Following option values: "Myself", "Legal guardian", "Deceased person"
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='Identity']/option[contains(text(),'Who is opting out?')]"))).click();
    #Select title: Following option values: "Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ms.", "Dr.", "Honorable", "Reverend", "Other"
    ele3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='Title']/option[@value='Mr.']") 
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",ele3)
    driver.find_element_by_id("FirstName").send_keys(firstname) 
    driver.find_element_by_id("MiddleName").send_keys(middlename)
    driver.find_element_by_id("LastName").send_keys(lastname)
    driver.find_element_by_id("DDSuffix").send_keys(suffix) 
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Email")))
    #driver.find_element_by_id("Email").send_keys(email) 
    # KEEP THIS DISABLED BC IT ACTUALLY SUBMITS 
    # driver.find_element_by_id("SubmitButton2").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    print("executed")
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.quit()
    return None
title="Mr"
middlename=""
firstname = "Joe"
lastname = "Musterman"
suffix=""
email = "joe@musterman.com"
acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email)
```

Could you help me why I cannot run it in the normal Chrome browser? I already did a lot of Stack Overflow research.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below solution and add chrome executable path. Check your chrome browser version and download chrome drivers from the below link :
https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os
import time
def acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email):
    # chrome_options = Options()
    # chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    # chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    # chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    # chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    # chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    # driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
    driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
    driver.set_window_size(1124, 850) # set browser size
    # link to data delete form
    print("opening data delete form")
    driver.get("https://isapps.acxiom.com/optout/optout.aspx#section8")
    #Select opt out segment: Following option values: "Mail", "Telemarketing", "Email"
    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.ss-values"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.ss-values"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ss-option' and contains(.,'Email')]"))).click()
    #ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='OptOutChoices2']/option[@value='Mail']") 
    #driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",ele)
    print("dropdown selected")
    #Select identity: Following option values: "Myself", "Legal guardian", "Deceased person"
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='Identity']/option[contains(text(),'Who is opting out?')]"))).click();
    #Select title: Following option values: "Mr.", "Mrs.", "Ms.", "Dr.", "Honorable", "Reverend", "Other"
    ele3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='Title']/option[@value='Mr.']") 
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",ele3)
    driver.find_element_by_id("FirstName").send_keys(firstname) 
    driver.find_element_by_id("MiddleName").send_keys(middlename)
    driver.find_element_by_id("LastName").send_keys(lastname)
    driver.find_element_by_id("DDSuffix").send_keys(suffix) 
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "Email")))
    #driver.find_element_by_id("Email").send_keys(email) 
    # KEEP THIS DISABLED BC IT ACTUALLY SUBMITS 
    # driver.find_element_by_id("SubmitButton2").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    print("executed")
    time.sleep(4)
    driver.quit()
    return None
title="Mr"
middlename=""
firstname = "Joe"
lastname = "Musterman"
suffix=""
email = "joe@musterman.com"
acxiom_DD_formfill(title, firstname, middlename, lastname, suffix, email)
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. I copied the correct chromedriver in the same folder as the program and run it with `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")`. This resulted in the same error message

Comment: I am using windows machine, for mac can you please keep your chrome driver under /usr/bin/ and update path is the code accordingly.

Comment: I also use Windows

Comment: please provide your driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")

Comment: I downloaded `ChromeDriver 80.0.3987.106` and put it in the same folder as the program: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")`

Comment: check your programs path and then you need to provide chromedriver executable path like a `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r" your program location/chromedriver.exe"` where you have extracted [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Comment: As you can see [here](https://imgur.com/a/hWj5eUN), this still does not work

Comment: your error is saying file not found check path is correct or not. lets move to chat section for further discussion